# Adding a temporary object to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have a custom class MDRect that i am trying to add an NSMutableArray

the array is a property:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* array;
```

it is initialized in the initMethod of the NSView subclass:

```
-(id)init {
array =  [NSMutableArray new];
return [super init];
 }
```

then i am trying to add an object in the array here:

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];    
mouseLoc = [self mouse:mouseLoc inRect:[self frame]];

CGSize temp;
NSLog(@"%f",mouseLoc.y - mouseLocation.y);
NSLog(@"%f",mouseLoc.x - mouseLocation.x);
temp.height = mouseLoc.y - mouseLocation.y;
temp.width = mouseLoc.x - mouseLocation.x;

tempRect.size = temp;
MDRect * rect = [[MDRect alloc] initWithColor:[NSColor orangeColor] andRect:tempRect];
[array addObject:rect];    




int i =     (int)array.count;
NSLog(@"%i",i);
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

But the object being is not being added to the array. it never returns any value other than 0 in the NSLog function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is your `init` method. You've got it quite wrong and it should look like this:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        array = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your problem is that you're not calling `super`'s init and assigning that to `self` and *then* setting up `array`. You're assigning `array` before you've even got a proper object and then you're not even returning anything that `array` has been set on, but rather returning the result of the super-class's `init` method. Then when you go to log `array.count`, `array` is `nil` and hence `i` becomes `0` (because messaging `nil` returns 0 in this circumstance).